# How to fix this "expiration not specified" issue according to GTMatrix?

Tags: css, image, cache-expiration, unspecified-behavior

I have a website [WeeTech Solution](https://www.weetechsolution.com). And whenever i check my website on “**GT Matrix**” is show me the number of issue like...
•   https://www.weetechsolution.com/css/content_slider_style.css (expiration not specified)

**How to fix this issue?**

Comment: This is not related to code. Please post it in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this code in your htaccess file.

```
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
        ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your site in html & php then you can use .htaccess file with below code and upload this `.htaccess` file to main root.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

If your site in .Net then yo can use `staticContent` inside `Web.config` file
code given below

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMaxAge="24:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
</staticContent>
```